# Lazyload is loading the same page or content over and over again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-lazyload

I'm a newbie when it comes to javascript or jquery stuff.

I have this website here: https://www.brindestip.com.br/brindes/Agendas

It's loading the same thing over and over again when i scroll. It wasn't like this before and i don't know what happened.

Here's the lazyload code:https://www.brindestip.com.br/js/lib/jquery.lazyload.js

Can you guys tell me whats wrong with the code so i can fix it? I tried looking at it myself and i saw other topics about people with similar situations but seems like my code is different from then and/or i didn't uderstand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i found out the problem...

I blocked cookies and forgot to allow then again lol

Sorry about that...